# Mean estimate and Least square estimate.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, probability-theory

This question is refers to the parameter estimate by average value given by the link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean

and least square estimates by the link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Least_squares

The both link talks about parameter estimation. Can we compare the both? It appears to me if we want to estimate two independent parameters then least square estimates becomes the mean estimates? Is it true? Can we prove it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the mean only happens to be the least squares parameter estimate for a select few models. In general, you are calculating something more complicated. We can demonstrate this using maximum likelihood methods:

Let $f(x;\alpha,\beta)=g(x;\alpha)h(x;\beta)$, so that the estimates for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are independent. Then the log-likelihood of a sample,$y=(y_1,y_2,...y_n)$ is:

$$\mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta;y)=\sum_y\log(g(y_i;\alpha))+\sum_y\log(h(y_i;\beta))$$

We maximize the log-likelihood by setting its derivatives to 0 (and checking that it is concave). These will be our maximum likelihood estimates $(\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta})$:

$$\hat{\alpha} = b: \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \alpha}\mid_{\alpha=b}=0 \implies \sum_y\frac{dg(y_i;\alpha)}{d\alpha}|_b\frac{1}{g(y_i;\alpha)}=0$$

And similarly for $\beta$.

Note that neither of these imply the mean is the estimator nor that least squares is the appropriate method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask under what condition least square solution is equal to mean, which I intended to ask actually?

Comment: I do understand maximum likelihood methods but my doubt is about least square and mean for certain cases. I am happy to give you upvote but I would appreciate your view on the question regarding model where least square solution is equal to mean.

Comment: @Creator if you are estimating a location parameter and want to minimize the squared error loss, then you will arrive at the mean as the minimizer.

Comment: Thank you, I am interested to prove your statement. Can you give me a lead how to do it?

Comment: @Creator Sure: formulate the product of $n$ gaussian density functions, all with the same parameters, but diffrerent $x$ values, where $f(x;\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}exp^{\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ . Assume you know $\sigma$, then take the log of this product to get a sum of log densities, you will see that it will reduce to finding a value of $\mu$ that minimizes the sum of squares.

Comment: It seems what you siad is done here:       https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood on the section "Continuous distribution, continuous parameter space"  Would you please let know if I understood correctly?

Comment: @Creator yep, you got it :)